# r.viewshed output location

Tags: grass-gis, viewshed, srtm, command-line, hgt

I'm very new on GRASS and trying to extract the viewshed of a SRTM HGT file.

This is what I've done so far:
(why I'm using GRASS command line this way is not in question. Please answer this same way)

```
grass --exec r.in.srtm -1 --overwrite input=S23W044.hgt

grass --exec g.list type=raster

grass --exec g.region raster=S23W044 -p

grass --exec r.viewshed input=S23W044 output=S23W044-shed coordinates=-43.5,-22.5
```

But I can't find my output file and don't know it format.

GRASS GIS 7.5.svn

Comment: To simplify your life you can gather all commands in a single script file, set file permission to "executable" and then run it all with --exec yourscript.sh|bat

Comment: I will code a Java program to execute these tasks. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out with

`grass --exec r.out.gdal in=S23W044-shed output=elevation.tif createopt="PROFILE=GeoTIFF,TFW=YES"`

but it came with no data...don't know if it was because some `r.viewshed` incorrect parameter.

** EDIT ** : 
Actualy it don't came empty. The default behaviour of `r.viewshed` is to produce a 0/1 map being 0=can't see and 1=can see.

I must add the `-e` parameter to get the elevation value for what I can see and null for what I can't see.

All is working now.

Comment: You are using GRASS in some non-standard way. Can you explain what is `grass --exec`? Without understanding this syntax, I don't see how to help. Please first start a normal GRASS session, and run your commands to make sure that all the steps work.

Comment: By using `grass --exec` I can execute grass commands without invoke GRASS environment. I need my bash available to do some other tasks. I don't want to work inside a `normal grass session`.